# Seeing something strange with UIImage on iOS 11

Tags: ios, uiimage, ios11

Some images appear to be semi transparent or some other stuff (color blind - so I'm not sure what exactly the problem)

https://www.dropbox.com/s/76wqg60khn1taws/Simulator%20Screen%20Shot%206%20Jun%202017%2C%2015.54.11.png?dl=0

Anyone else sees this?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and it turned out to be the problem with color profiles. I'm not sure which one wasn't working, but when I've edited the pictures to use *Generic RGB Profile* the images looked fine on iOS11.

I've used Mac OS built in *ColorSync Utility* for this.